# How to correctly create a date with a specific format?

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have the following doubt related how to create a format date in Java.

In a Java application I have to create a date (the value have to be the current date) formatted in this way: **2015-05-26** (**yyyy-mm-dd**)

So I know that I can obtain the current date simply build a new `java.util.Date` object, this way:

```
Date dataDocumento = new Date();
```

but how can I specify my date format?

Tnx

Comment: See the following: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Date does not have a concept of a format, it's simply a container of the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Use a DateFormat when you want to display the date value in a particular format

Comment: There are 8 outdated answers below. The correct and current answer in 2017 is `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString()` (it was even a valid answer when the question was asked in 2015). You may supply a different time zone depending on your needs.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date c= sdf.parse("2015-05-26");
String date=sdf.format(c);
System.out.println(date);
```

To format the current date in yyyy-MM-dd format you can try like this

```
Date date = new Date();
String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
```

Kindly refer [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: ok but the problem is I have to create a new current date and don't use 2015-05-26 as you do

Comment: @AndreaNobili:- Updated my answer! Please check now!

Comment: you've created a formated string not a date object

Answer (score 9):

You have to use **[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**Note** That `MM` stands for month and not `mm`.

And you format your date and parse it as a `Date` object like this:

```
Date dt = sf.parse(sf.format(new Date()));
```

Using `format(new Date())` you can format a `new Date()`.

Comment: You say "you format your date like this" and then you show how to *parse* a date, which is the opposite of formatting.

Comment: Yes @Jesper you are right, I'm Editing it.

Answer (score 4):

`java.util.Date` objects do not have a format by themselves. They are just timestamp values, just like an `int` is just a number, without any inherent format. So, there is no such thing as "a `Date` object with the format `yyyy-MM-dd`".

The format is determined at the moment you convert the `Date` to a `String`. You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert a `Date` to a `String` in a specific format. For example:

```
Date date = new Date();

DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String text = fmt.format(date);

System.out.println(text);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: The best solution for me, to get a formatted date inline! ++

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class GetCurrentDateTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // you can change the format as you like
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can use simple date format class for this:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
     Date dataDocumento = new Date();
     sdf.format(dataDocumento);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following-

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());
```

MoreOver You can use any of given formet if required-

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS").format(new Date());
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS Z").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Code

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

```
/**
 *
 * Java program to show how to format date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
 * Examples. Java allows to include date, time and timezone information
 * while formatting dates in Java.
 *
 * @author http://java67.blogspot.com
 */
public class DateFormatExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // This is how to get today's date in Java
        Date today = new Date();

        //If you print Date, you will get un formatted output
        System.out.println("Today is : " + today);

        //formatting date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
        SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : " + date);

        //Another Example of formatting Date in Java using SimpleDateFormat
        DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd/MM/yy pattern : " + date);

        //formatting Date with time information
        DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS");
        date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : " + date);

        //SimpleDateFormat example - Date with timezone information
        DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS Z");
        date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
        System.out.println("Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SSZ : " + date);

    } 

}
```

Output

```
Today is : Tue May 26 16:11:27 IST 2015

Today in dd-MM-yyyy format : 26-05-2015

Today in dd/MM/yy pattern : 26/05/15

Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS : 26-05-15:16:11:316

Today in dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SSZ : 26-05-15:16:11:316 +0530
```